# CMake Find library issues if "lib" is a directory in the path

Tags: cmake, lib

I have found a workaround for this problem, but I don't know why it works:
I am creating a CMake toolchain for a platform with many libs provided by COMPANY in a few locations.

Note: `SDK_PATH` is passed as an environment variable.

As an example, the provided C++ lib is at `${SDK_PATH}/COMPANY/stl/libc++-COMPANY/lib/libc++.so` and another lib is at `${SDK_PATH}/lib/COMPANY/libCOMPANY_ext_logging.so`

For the C++ lib, I can find it as expected with:

```
find_library(CPP
    NAMES
    c++
    HINTS
    ${SDK_PATH}/COMPANY/stl/libc++-COMPANY/lib
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
```

However, I can not find the logging library with:

```
find_library(LOGGING
    NAMES
    COMPANY_ext_logging
    HINTS
    ${SDK_PATH}/lib/COMPANY
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
```

However, I have found that if I copy the problematic libraries into a further subdirectory "lib" then things work (I guess that is a keyword CMake looks for somehow)
IE if I copy the logging lib to `${SDK_PATH}/lib/COMPANY/lib/libCOMPANY_ext_logging.so` and alter the find command to be:

```
find_library(LOGGING
    NAMES
    COMPANY_ext_logging
    HINTS
    ${SDK_PATH}/lib/COMPANY/lib
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
```

then things work fine. Which makes little sense to me.

I believe I had this working without the workaround about a year ago, but am unsure (I ran into this while updating both my CMake and the version of the company libraries)

Is there better CMake syntax I could use to avoid needing the workaround and still find libraries at the path `${SDK_PATH}/lib/COMPANY` ?

Note2: I have tried using "Paths" rather than "Hints" with no change in results (The successful finds still work, and the failing ones still fail)

Comment: How is `SDK_PATH` determined? The `HINTS` argument is typically reserved for paths found via system introspection. But if this is a *hard-coded* path, the `PATHS` argument should be used here instead. See the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html).

Comment: SDK_PATH is an environment variable. I have tried "PATHS" as well with the same results (Both for success and failures)

I am honestly not too clear on the difference from the docs, but the result seems to be the same either way on that front.

Comment: Neither way for search `COMPANY_ext_logging.so` works for me. This is because `COMPANY_ext_logging.so` is a **wrong string to search**: it contains library **suffix** (`.so`) but doesn't contain library **prefix** (`lib`). You need to search either `COMPANY_ext_logging` or `libCOMPANY_ext_logging.so`.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, that is a typo from me generalizing my example. Sorry about that.